# Grid system doesn't resize properly on mobile devices or small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Command `col-xs-whatever` doesn't work and makes break lines on mobile view or small screens.

Note: I also tested the class `.col-` as Bootstrap 4 specifies in the documentation but it still doesn't work.

It doesn't resize properly and pile up, here is the relevant code:

```css
.navbar{
    background-image: cornflowerblue;
}
#mainNav{
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 3%;
    background-color: white;
}
body{
    background-color: grey;
}
#navContent{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 3%;
}
#final{
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 3%;
    background-color: white;
}
#searchFormContent{
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
#navToggler{
    float: right;
}
.navbar-toggler{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <section class="row" id="mainNav">
            <div class="col-12">
                <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md">
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-7">
                        <form class="form-inline" id="searchForm" role="search">
                            <div class="input-group" id="searchFormContent">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Busqueda">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <span id="destiny1"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-3">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navToggler" aria-controls="navToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navToggler">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <span id="destiny2"></span>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            </section>
            </div>
            </body>
```

Comment: can i see your design view in mobile ?

Comment: @SanjayPrajapati This is a screenshot in mobile device. Note you can see in the snippet still doesnt work properly: https://imgur.com/JJpGzFe

Comment: but i need your  need mobile view screen  short

Comment: Already linked, check my last answer

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: see edit + comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is your desired outcome as you did not specify.

I changed `col-xs-whatever` to `col-whatever` after that you were applying margin and border on a `row` with CSS applied to `#mainNav` that is why all columns could not fit inside.

So I moved `row` in a wrapping nav and removed `row` from `#mainNav`

Here is changed code:

```css
.navbar{
    background-image: cornflowerblue;
}
#mainNav{
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 3%;
    background-color: white;
}
body{
    background-color: grey;
}
#navContent{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 3%;
}
#final{
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 3%;
    background-color: white;
}
#searchFormContent{
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
#navToggler{
    float: right;
}
.navbar-toggler{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
        <section id="mainNav">    
            <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md row">
                <div class="col-2 col-md-2">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>    
                <div class="col-8 col-md-7">
                    <form class="form-inline" id="searchForm" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group" id="searchFormContent">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Busqueda">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <span id="destiny1"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 col-md-3">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navToggler" aria-controls="navToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                            </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navToggler">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span id="destiny2"></span>
                </div>
            </nav>    
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, still doesnt work with your code, check how it looks here: https://imgur.com/QrYUnLk

Comment: And if I move class row to the section it would be the same?

Comment: no because you would be overriding row style with your css for #mainNav. I edited now my answer and it should work I moved row class into nav element. Here is working example  http://jsbin.com/luteyiyaxa/edit

Comment: Only problem on extra narrow screens is that your content in col-1 is too wide to fit so it jumps on other line, you should consider go with col-2 col-8 col-2 structure it works well.

Comment: Still doesnt work, this how it looks on Nexus with your code: https://imgur.com/PZgVdbC  . Also tried col-2 col-8 col-2 but nothing

Comment: @SilverSurfer here is updated fiddle just with changed classes http://jsbin.com/novidudide/edit?html,css,js and here is screenshot with Nexus https://imgur.com/a/M1DF4

Comment: @ iamwtk Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155924/discussion-between-silversurfer-and-iamwtk).

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by iamwtk, part of the problem is that you have to use col-XYZ in place of col-xs-XYZ, but the biggest problem is the content of the grid: both Brand and Busqueda exceed the width of the col, breaking the row... try play a little with col distribution and changing the width of "searchFormContent" making it dynamic ;)